# Nouns list followed by 他

Tags: words

I would like to know what the word 「他」means in the following sentence.

引火性のもの　（ガソリン、ベンジン、**シンナー他{ほか}**）の近くで使用しないで下さい。

Does it means **'...and other things that are able to catch fire'** or **'besides gasoline, Benzin and thinner'**?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's the former. Check if there is の before 他.

- `A、B、C他` means "A, B, C and others"
- `A、B、Cの他` means "besides A, B and C"

Comment: 「Win, Mac の他 Linux にも対応」などとも言えるので except はまずいのではないかと…

Comment: おっしゃるとおりです、直しました。